# What's this new button type called?

Tags: interface-design, terminology, mobile, android, google-material-design

I've seen this type of buttons - no background and with an icon on top - in some places in Android 10 settings (Lineage OS 17, if that's important) and in one another application which uses slightly different design language.

The question is - is there some specific name for this type of buttons? I tried googling it, looking for it in Google's Material Design guidelines and found no info about it.

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: Button without a background or border? It's just a button. There aren't names for everything.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Sure, there aren't names for everything, but there are several types of buttons and not only in Material Design and guidelines for it are very detailed, so there has to be some name for it, at least I hope so.

Comment: I see **icons** which may or may not be clickable... using large icons is no different than using tiny icons for the search or back "buttons". Really not certain why using clickable icons is perceived as "new".

Answer (score 1):

In Android, it's simply called "[borderless button](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button#Borderless)".

> #### Borderless button
>
> One design that can be useful is a "borderless" button. Borderless buttons resemble basic buttons except that they have no borders or background but still change appearance during different states, such as when clicked.

[The icon on top](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:drawableTop) is an attribute of [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) which is inherited by [`Button`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button).